# Do I really need Java to compile Java?

Tags: java

I am on a new install of Elementary OS and I am trying to compile OpenJDK 8 from source. I have downloaded everything but when I run ./configure I get the following...

> configure: Could not find a valid Book JDK. You might be able to fix
>   this by running 'apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk'.

But I do not want to install Java 7 so what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you do. The Java compiler is *written in Java*.

Comment: So I would need the JRE to compile, ergo I would need the JRE source is that correct?

Comment: @Jackie A lot of the JRE source is Java too, so you still need Java to compile it.

Comment: I mean at some point someone has to be able to compile it without a java machine (first time a new platform comes out). It would be nice to know the base component it is looking for

Comment: @Jackie The very first Java compiler was written in C, but I don't think it was ever published publicly, and it wouldn't be new enough to compile modern Java. Nowadays, the standard Java compiler is written in Java, so you do need Java to compile it; this is called a [self-hosting compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29). If you can find (or write) a different Java compiler that's written in C++ or something and is at least half-way modern, then you can bootstrap Java without Java, but I'm not aware of any existing ones out there.

Answer (score 2):

You need java in order to compile your java programs.
You need the javac file in you bin folder within java to successfully compile them.

Hope this helps!